# Calculating large travel distance matrix

Tags: openstreetmap, distance-matrix

I need to calculate a really large travel distance matrix 3600^2 to solve a TSP problem between points. I have the coordinates of the points and also the addresses.

How can I calculate this matrix quickly?

I tried through OSM but the calculation is one each time and it will take me 150 days I also tried to calculate at the same time but it doesn't give.

Is there a solution to this at all?

I've been looking for a solution for a long time, but I haven't found one for this amount of points.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: OSRM, if properly set up on sufficient hardware, should have no issues calculating that matrix for you.

Comment: im using in http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/{start_point};{endpoint} and its very easy. is there any faster way to get the matrix?

Comment: How large is the road network? Is it possible to download it somewhere?

Comment: 3600^2 is very big and i need the drive distance that is the problem

Comment: Can you clarify why installing OSRM locally (or another OSM-based router capable of calculating this matrix) to perform this operation is a problem for you? If it takes too much time, perform these calculations on a faster system.

Answer (score 0):

**Asynchronous matrices** are suitable for your request. I know that Distancematrix.ai have this option. In my case, the calculation took 2 or 3 days, you can also try to look for other analogues online.